# writing an "if" statement in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android. I'm trying to write a method that has an if statement in it.What I'm trying to get happen is "if the text in the Textview is equal to a certain value, change the background image in the layout." I know the setting background bit works, I've narrowed the problem to the If statement. in the below code showBook is a TextView, tvString is the string that holds the value of showBook. bgview is the layout id.

```
        String tvString = showBook.getText().toString(); 
    bookDisp.setText(tvString); 
    View mainbg = bgview.getRootView(); 
    if(bookDisp.equals("John")){ 
    mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dbvjohn);
```

the problem is the line

```
if(bookDisp.equals("John")){
```

it doesn't want to compare bookDisp with a string "John". It will however will work if I compare two textviews for example

```
if(bookDisp.equals(newTextView)){
```

so I think the problem is the .equals bit. what code would I use to compare bookDisp with "John"? it's not `if(bookDisp = ("John")){` because Eclipse wants me to change bookDisp to a string. So what would be the proper code to compare a textview bookDisp to a string "John"?

Never mind folks! I figured it out, and the error wasn't in this method at all, but in another method. I had `+ cursor.getString(1) + " ";` in that method, so the strings in the textviews were displaying as "John " and the "if" statement above was looking for "John".

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
if ("John".equals(bookDisp.getText().toString())) {
```

Comment: Actually there is no reason to put the constant to the left here, as you won't be getting any `null` results from the functions. But still good practice. :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use:

```
bookDisp.getText().toString().equals("John");
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to compare strings like below::

tvString.equals("John");

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text from the TextView in order to see if it equals "John".
do:
bookDisp.getText().equals("John")

That should work. getText for TextViews returns an editable. Heres the class so you can work with it:
[Editable Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html)